# when magnific popup open page scroll top

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have a problem with magnific popup. when I click on button - modal window open and page scroll to top. When close modal window - position of scroll return position reverse. I dont won't to page scroll top. maybe anybody has same problem?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step please share your code so we can have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set fixedContentPos option of MagnificPopup to false. By default it's set to auto and when you click the button the page scrolls to top.

```
$('#popupid').magnificPopup({ fixedContentPos = false, //Options... });
```

**EDIT**

Try to use this option too (it adds the class when popup gets open and delete it when popup gets closed):

```
callbacks: {
    open: function() {
       jQuery('body').addClass('magnificpopupnoscroll');
    },
    close: function() {
       jQuery('body').removeClass('magnificpopupnoscroll');
    }
}
```

And add this css class:

```
body.magnificpopupnoscroll{
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: when i use fixedContentPos option my modal window scroll with all page